# basic doubt on policy iteration

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

consider the policy iteration algorithm for a finite state MDP. Suppose the initial policy is a stochastic policy. Now, can the optimal policy be deterministic after improvements ? Or, can we say that always the optimal policy will be a stochastic one ? Confused about this. Any ideas will be helpful. The reason I am asking this question is that in the absence of model i.e. when we need to need to use Monte Carlo methods then each of the improved policies must be a stochastic one to make sure action-value function estimates are near equal to the mean.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried looking at some small examples?  If so, what happened in those examples?

Comment: @D.W: we need to use just $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by that, or how that responds to my questions.  Please edit your question to provide more details on what you have tried -- and I suggest you look at some examples and see what happens with them.

Answer (score 1):

A stochastic policy can perfectly represent a deterministic policy by assigning probability 1 to a unique action.

Depending on how you are adjusting the policy it might take time to converge into a deterministic one, however it can get there in the limit.